# What does this macro mean in linux kernel code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

see i found one config file in which this are macro defined

```
#
# Input Device Drivers
#
CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_ADP5588 is not set
CONFIG_KEYBOARD_ATKBD=y
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_QT2160 is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_LKKBD is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_GPIO is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_TCA6416 is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_MATRIX is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_LM8323 is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_MAX7359 is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_NEWTON is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_OPENCORES is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_STOWAWAY is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_SUNKBD is not set
CONFIG_KEYBOARD_OMAP4=y
```

But i dont understand which macro should i enable for connecting USB keyboard with pandabord  ?Is there any documation for this config files macro?

Comment: These are not macros and your question is not programming-related.

Comment: Maybe you want a configuration for USB HID http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class like `CONFIG_USB_HID` and others but stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: And you can get some documentation with e.g. `make menuconfig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not macros. This is the config file generated before compiling a kernel generated by 
"make menuconfig" or "make xconfig" etc.

These indicate what drivers are to be built when kernel is compiled.

'y' means support is built into the kernel

'm' means the driver is built as a kernel module

Answer (score 1):

Check the compatible driver code and with each driver there will be macro defined in makefile. Select that macro as `y` or `m` based on your requirement. Also don't forget to select the dependent drivers for your keyboard  which may be USB core and hid drivers.

I will suggest better run `make menuconfig` for your architecture and select your keyboard driver. That will enable all dependent drivers.

Answer (score 0):

These are not macros as they are here, but become macros for the C code to use in the generated include/generated/autoconf.h.

- `CONFIG_XXXXXX=y` will become `#define CONFIG_XXXXXX 1` later.
- `CONFIG_XXXXXX=m` will become `#define CONFIG_XXXXXX_MODULE 1` later.

Items not defined here will not be `#defined` later.